# @Transactional two transaction managers, one transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have a situation where I have two data sources, each has a transaction manager, txm1 and txm2.  I need to be able to rollback both if there is any failure.  I noticed I can't annotate a single method with 2 @Transactional annotations.

What would be the best way to do this?

for instance I can't do this:

```
@Transactional("txm1")
@Transactional("txm2")
public void updateBothDatabases() {
   db1Repo.update();
   db2Repo.update();
   someService.invoke() //throws exception.
   //needs to rollback db1 and db2.
}
```

Comment: Even if it would work it wouldn't work. As it still would be 2 separate transactions and it could happen that one could commit and the other still fail leading to weird situations. So either use XA (which has slightly better guarantees) or use a different way in which you compensate yourself (i.e. delete/rollback manually).

Comment: Take a look at the [ChainedTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/transaction/ChainedTransactionManager.html)